# The dangers of stepwise variable selection in regression

Tags: regression, stepwise-regression

This paper discusses some of the dangers of using stepwise variable selection procedures:

http://www.auburn.edu/~tds0009/Articles/Whittingham%20et%20al.%202006.pdf

I'm struggling to understand Figure 1b. The authors generated data according to the model $y = 0.5x + e$. Datasets of sample size $n$ = 10 were drawn and a linear model fitted. Figure 1a shows the distribution of slopes estimated by these linear models. A variable selection procedure was implemented, by testing each estimated slope against a slope of zero. A slope was discarded if the test was insignificant. Figure 1b shows the resultant distribution of slopes, following the variable selection procedure.

Here's what I don't understand...I would have expected any estimated betas that were actually zero or very close to zero to be discarded, as they would have been insignificant in the t-test. I would have expected any estimated betas that were closer to -1 or say about 0.5 and above to be retained. Therefore, I would have expected the Figure 1b to have a gap around the zero mark (where betas were discarded) and all other betas to be retained. What is bizarre to me is that the betas that were actually zero have retained, while most other have discarded.

Would somebody like to explain the distribution of betas in Figure 1b, and why these betas have been retained?

Answer (score 6):

The figure shows the distribution of estimated slope parameters over all models, not just those which were significantly different from zero. The spike at zero represents all the models where the slope was deemed insignificant, and so a zero-slope model was used. The point is to demonstrate that the variable-selection procedure leads to estimates of $\beta$ which are either zero (and thus far too low) or extremely large (because the larger estimates are "more significant").

Comment: Ok so the variable selection procedure resulted in retaining only betas which were well above their real value (0.5). But presumably it isn't always the case that retained betas are well above their actual value? I presume their closeness to their real value depends on sample size and variation in the response variable?

Comment: Variable selection will always result in a bias towards zero, as small effect estimates are treated as zero, while large effect estimates are left untouched. It will depend on the power of your statistical test (and thus on sample size, etc) whether the true value gets accepted or not, but there will always be a cutoff.